# Cocoa RTF: NSData vs. NSAttributedString?

Tags: cocoa, nsdata, rtf, nsattributedstring

My Cocoa app needs to produce documents using RTF. After much searching, I haven't yet found a Cocoa-native way to provide footers in an RTF document. For this reason it appears I have to generate RTF code rather than just saving an NSAttributedString in RTF format.

Let's say I'm producing RTF code such as:

```
....\pgnstart1 {\fs24\scaps\b\qc Table 1\par\ql\fs18 \par....
```

Should I initially store it to an NSData object, or to an NSAttributedString object, prior to saving it to disk?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: Did you find the RTF methods in [NSAttributedString AppKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/RTFFromRange:documentAttributes:)? You can create/generate RTF to/from `NSAttributedString`s. What did you try so far?

Comment: @boyfarell he says he needs to generate it so he has footers. I don't fully get the question either though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think Cocoa’s subset of RTF reading/writing supports footers. You’ll have to create them yourself, but getting them into your RTF stream will be a chore. If you have an RTF parser you’d have to post-process the raw RTF your get from NSAttributedString to insert your custom RTF.

Not fun. The RTF parser was never really designed to be extensible.

Comment: Fortunately I'm porting an app that already knows how to produce the RTF code I need. (It was indeed a lot of work writing it).

Comment: (Whoops - timed out during edit.) I can easily write the RTF code needed directly to a text file on the disk.

It might be helpful to use NSAttributedStrings to [calculate the text height][1]. If so I need to get my RTF code into the form of an NSAttributedString.

I guess I need to 1) get my stream of raw rtf code into an NSData object and then 2) use initWithRTF:documentAttributes: to get that into an NSAttributedString. It seems convoluted. :) But would that be the correct approach?

[1]:http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html

Comment: Yes, that’s the approach I’d use.